# How to use Cognos Analytics to define different aggregation functions(Ex: average, sum) for different columns?

Tags: cognos

I want to build a report and suppose I have the following table in my report:

```
2012 OCT 7547  697  0.08
     NOV 9570  373  0.04
     DEC 1879  107  0.05
```

I want to create a total row: for the first numeric column I want to calculate mean, for the second total and for the third sum. How can I do that?

I am using the 11 version of Cognos Analytics

Comment: We are using Cognos 10 so I want to confirm the terminology first. Are you building this report in report studio?

Comment: @AquaticallyChallengedFish yes, exactly

Answer (score 0):

Report studio will add, automatically, summary objects to reports so that's there for free; the only question after that is the nature of the aggregation.

What's the source of the metadata that you're using?  Is it a package or module?   What's the aggregation which has been defined in the model?  Why can't you leverage what's all ready there?  If you look at the generated SQL, what aggregations are being done?

Total is sum aggregation so I'm not sure what you mean when you say you want one query item to aggregate as sum and another as total.  Could you explain that pls.

Answer (score 0):

1. Select the first numeric column.
2. On the context-sensitive toolbar, select the summarize tool (sigma) and click Average.
3. Select the second and third numeric columns.
4. On the context-sensitive toolbar, select the summarize tool and click Total.

Cognos will separate the averages and totals into different summary rows.  If you want them all in one row:

1. Unlock the report by clicking on the More button in the top right of the screen.
2. Select the label cell on the total summary row.
3. On the context-sensitive toolbar, click the Split Cell tool.
4. Select the average (first numeric column) and drag it to the total row.
5. (if you want to) Change the label on the total summary row.
6. Lock the report.
7. Select the average summary row and delete it.

You may want to find some basic Cognos report development training.  IBM and others have produced videos on this topic and posted them to YouTube.  There are also vendors (IBM partners?) who provide this training.  Or just contact your Cognos support staff in your IT division.